# History of monotone convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, math-history

The theorem often be called Lebesgue's MCT or Levi's theorem. Who did originally prove it or what is the contribution of Lebesgue and Levi respectively?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think this is thoroughly discussed in [**Lebesgue's Theory of Integration: Its Origins and Development**](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/lebesgues-theory-of-integration-its-origins-and-development) by Thomas Hawkins. This book is well known and widely available (for purchase, in libraries, on mathematicians' bookshelves, etc.) --- if you have more than a passing interest in things like this, then you should get a copy of this book.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Yes. I had seen the book. But I cant found a detailed discussion on MCT.